# Fast C++ implementation of sparse binary matrices

Tags: matrix, c++, sparse-matrix

I am looking for the subject. The size of matrices will be around 1000x2000 elements with linear amount of ones (say, 6000 ones in the whole matrix).

The operations I will use the most:

- iterating over elements of particular column;
- iterating over elements of particular row;
- getting submatrix by columns;
- solving undetermined linear system (over Galois field $\mathbb F_2$).

Before starting to implement it myself I want to ask the community about the existing libraries. Also if you have some ideas on implementation - feel free to share.

P.S. Memory usage is not of much importance for me.

Comment: PETSc is fast, scalable, has C wrappers and can perform these tasks.

Comment: I briefly looked at PETSC manual. Are you sure it can work with binary matrices. My feeling is that it is only for real matrices...

Comment: You are correct that it does not have a direct handling for binary matrices. Your problem is not especially large, are you sure that this deficiency is prohibitive?

Comment: @Spencer Bryngelson, the last point is very specific (Galois field), and to my knowledge general sparse matrices packages do not have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CADO-NFS [1] (implementation of the Number Field Sieve algorithm for factoring integers) has an implementation of sparse binary matrices and linear solve over specific fields (I am not 100% sure it has the Galois field that you need, but it probably has something at least similar).

[1] http://cado-nfs.gforge.inria.fr/

Comment: This looks much more promising. I will dig in the library to see if I can find ready-made solution. Thanks!